# Using .net VB I ftp an image to woocommerce but it wrongly places it in a non existent URL

Tags: php, functions

I place an image using a FTP upload(.net vb) in the folder https://streetgym.co.za/wp-content/uploads/ProductImage/2-807.jpg; wordpress then creates a url AT https://streetgym.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/73089-271-M.07.jpg. But this url does not have the contents of 2-807.jpg it has no content (404 error when pasted to browser).

How can i enforce that the 2-807.jpg is carried correctly to the year/month folder in /uploads

Comment: "wordpress then creates a url" How is it doing this? WordPress will not automatically do this if you upload an image with FTP. If you want to upload media from an external application and have WordPress store it in the correct directory, and display it in the media library then you should use the REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/

Comment: @Jacob ; wordpress(woocommerce) does this for ftp downloads to /wp-content/uploads . . . I will look into the REST API link !